# Mail body is not updating after changing Assigned To in Workflow Task (SharePoint 2013)

Tags: 2013, workflow

For some reason, sometime I need to change the `Assigned To` of a task. So I am editing the task item and saving it.

[image]

So the new `Assigned To` is getting an email.

[image]

**Now the problem is lookup values are not updating in the mail body. It is remaining as the first mail.**

Comment: What is that Look up field, which is not updating?

Comment: Three columns from related item: **Assigned To (Custom)** (People or Group), **Modified By** (People or Group) and **Comment** (Multiple line of text)